# Preventing an iterator from traversing past the end of a container

Tags: debugging, iterator, containers, c++17, assertion

I'm working on my own `for_each` type function by some integer `N`.

This is what my function currently looks like:

```
template<typename Container, typename Function>
void for_each_by_n( Container&& cont, Function f, unsigned increment_by ) {
    using std::begin;
    auto it = begin(cont);

    using std::end;
    auto end_it = end(cont);

    while ( it != end_it ) { // traverse the full container
        f(*it);  // call the function pointer - object etc.
        for ( unsigned n = 0; n < increment_by; ++n ) {
            // here I want to increment the pointer as long as the next iteration of
            // increment_by is within the bounds of the range of the container
            if ( .... tried many things .... ) return; // and or break;
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

My last attempt of the inner if statement was this:

```
if ( n % increment_by > (cont.size() - n) ) return; // and or break;
```

However, I keep getting a debug assertion failure that I can not iterate past the end of the index of the container. This has me stumped and I don't know how to prevent the iteration from going past the end.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I walked away from my computer for about 30 seconds to a minute, and then it came to me. I was completely over thinking it and it was actually a simple fix.

All I had to do for the if statement was this:

```
if ( it == end_it ) return;
```

Now it works appropriately. There was no need to do the calculations based on where the index pointer was compared to the end. All I had to do was compare if they were equal and if so just return.

So the full complete function now looks like this:

```
// positive direction from begin to end only
template<typename Container, typename Function>
void for_each_by_n(Container&& cont, Function f, unsigned increment_by) {
    using std::begin;
    auto it = begin(cont);

    using std::end;
    auto end_it = end(cont);

    while (it != end_it ) {
        f(*it);
        for ( unsigned n = 0; n < increment_by; ++n ) {
            if (it == end_it) {
                return;
            }
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

It must have been that coders_block syndrome...

Answer (score 0):

They key here is to realize that you want the first element of every chunk of `cont`, and every chunk is `increment_by` elements. Hence there are `cont.size()/increment_by` chunks. No need to check if you reached the last iterator, just count chunks.

There's no need for `++it`. Use `std::advance(increment_by)`, it's a lot faster for random access iterators.

Comment: That's funny that you had mentioned `std::advanced`, because I was actually looking at that from `cppreference` however, it is new to me so I was struggling a bit to try and incorporate it. I'm calling this function here above and passing in a lambda as the function parameter.